# MYSQL Create Table Error "A table must have 1 Column"

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a MYSQL Table in my database using php:

```
 $sql="CREATE TABLE $URL(Image BLOB,Rating INT(255),Id INT KEY AUTO_INCREMENT)";
```

However, it errors out and says: A table must have at least 1 column.

Why is it doing this?

Here is the full php file used to create the table:

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="questapic"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="tabledirector";

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 

 // get data that sent from form 
 $TN = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$TQ = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['q']);
$CR = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['creator']);
$datetime=date("d/m/y"); //create date time
$R1=rand(5000, 15000000);
$R2=rand(5000, 15000000);
$R3=rand(5000, 15000000);

$URL = $TN . $R1 . $TQ . $R2 . $CR . $R3;

$URL=str_replace(" ","#%","$URL");


mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(URL,topic)VALUES('$URL','$TQ')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$sql="CREATE TABLE $URL(Image BLOB,Rating INT(255),Id INT KEY AUTO_INCREMENT)";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


if (!$result) die (mysql_error());
mysql_close();

header("location:Your_Special_Code_Is.php?id=$URL");



?>
```

Comment: it works here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2f32

Comment: Create a table name$url?

Comment: Do you mean `URL` not `$URL`?

Comment: $URL is associated with one of my variables I have posted the full code to give you a better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE ".$URL."(Image BLOB,Rating INT(255),Id INT KEY AUTO_INCREMENT)";
```

Comment: Yes because special characters are replaced by 'space'. try to edit the concatenation of your `$URL` variable.

Comment: Tip: try `Ctrl+F5` when refreshing your browser.:)